# can I have two different logs if I use express in my HTTP request in Firebase Cloud Function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to make 2 endpoints using Google Cloud Functions and express in Node JS. the code in my `index.ts` is like this

```
import {onRequest} from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import * as express from "express";

const app = express();

app.use("/api/example1", (req, res) => res.send("Hei"));
app.use("/api/example2", (req, res) => res.send("yoooo"));


exports.app = onRequest(app);
```

I build it using Firebase emulator, and I will get two different endpoints like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/blueray-cargo/us-central1/app/api/example1

http://127.0.0.1:5000/blueray-cargo/us-central1/app/api/example2
```

I have two endpoints there. but If I hit those 2 endpoints, in my Cloud Functions log, I will have this data

[image]

as you can see from the image above, even though I hit two different endpoints it seems that it will be eventually grouped into one report i.e `function[us-central1-app]`.

my question is ....

can I automatically have two different logs if I use express in my HTTP request in Cloud Function? so I can differentiate if there is an error, i can figure out where this error is coming from, from endpoint 1 or endpoint 2? or is there a workaround to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's the way the logging works in Cloud Functions.  You are free to modify the text of your *own* messaging to provide more diagnostics for each request to make it easier to do your own debugging, but you can't change the logging provided by the Cloud Functions platform.